# SSRS Toggleitem error message - Property Value Is Not Valid

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I have created an SSRS report, whilst following the Wiseowl tutorial on youtube, I get to the part where I need to toggleitem to create an expandable/collapsable field. I am getting an error message below. I cannot work out what I have done wrong, any help appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You'll need to provide much more info. Please show your report design including any relevant settings such as the toggle item expression that you have used etc. At the moment it's difficult to understand what your issue is. Please read this for guidance https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @AlanSchofield I have updated my question with a couple more screenshots. I am trying to toggle the Region textbox at the top, I am not using an expression, I am simply trying to choose this field to toggle. You can see what I am trying to do in this video tutorial, at 9:45.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ma_yo6VB2xs

Comment: I worked it out, I needed to open group properties and tick 'display can be toggled by this report item'

Comment: Glad you worked it out. FYI: The toggle item expression is, in this case, the name of the textbox. It's still an expression even if it's doesn't have any real logic.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out, I needed to open group properties and tick 'display can be toggled by this report item'